# If the derivative tends to infinity near a point, does that mean that the derivative does not exist at that point?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, $f \in (C^0 [0, \infty)) \cap C^1(0, \infty)) $ and $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f'\to \infty$ does this imply that the derivative (on the right) $f'(0)$ does not exist?

Comment: Yes by Darboux.

Comment: @zhw. This one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29 , right  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously true due to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29 as @zhw pointed out.